# A class does not deduct its template arguments

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Why doesn't this class deduce its template arguments?

```
template <class T>
struct Ohlc
{
    T o;
    T h;
    T l;
    T c;
};

template <class T, template <class> class Coll>
class OhlcCollector
{
private:

    using Container = Coll<Ohlc<T>>;

public:

    OhlcCollector(Container & container)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Ohlc<double>> v;

    // error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'OhlcCollector'
    OhlcCollector collector(v);

    //but this comples
    OhlcCollector<double, std::vector> collector(v);
}
```

What is the rule applied here?

What kind of arguments are deduced and what are not?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction

Comment: `template <class> class Coll` -> `template <class...> class Coll`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. did you try this?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/T8nos5MoP

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. With GCC it also compiles with `template <class T, template <class> class Coll>`. So looks like it is a question about MSVC compiler 19.28.29915

Comment: @n none of that explains why you can pass vector to <class> yet the CTAD deduction fails.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. with MSVC `template <class...> class Coll` does not compile

Comment: "With GCC it also compiles" I am not sure why gcc compiles it without the ellipsis. clang and icc reject it without the ellipsis and accept with the ellipsis. MSVC is probably just buggy as usual.

Comment: It fails because `std::vector` has more than one template parameter and does not match `template<class>`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. try this https://wandbox.org/permlink/WS432StfkEOxJCkU, with GCC 12

Comment: MSVC will compile with `template <class T, template <class K, class=std::allocator<K>> class Coll>` but this is of course not what people usually need. It is supposed to work with the ellipsis.

Comment: I know gcc compiles it without the ellipsis. I don't know why it does that. I think it should not.

Comment: Hi Dmitiano, to me the handling of nested templates is always difficult. I tried your code in godbolt.org. I modified your code only by numbering the `collector` and it compiled using X86-64 gcc11.1 as compiler[ https://godbolt.org/z/6TEqTPxoE ]. But even the second expression `OhlcCollector<double, std::vector> collector2(v);` fails using x64 msvc 19.latest[ https://godbolt.org/z/qorfevGq5 ] as compiler. These difficulties leeds me to be a lazy guy and avoid nested templates [ https://godbolt.org/z/nq788qjGb ].